# Redux does not update state even if reducer is triggered

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to use redux for react.

i have action creator:

```
export const API_PATH_UPDATED = 'query/apiPathUpdated';

export const apiPathUpdated = (apiPath) => ({
  type: API_PATH_UPDATED,
  payload: {
    apiPath,
  },
});
```

This action creator is called in this function:

```
const getUpcoming = useCallback(
    () => dispatch(apiPathUpdated('/movie/upcoming')),
    [dispatch],
  );
```

And should update my state with the following reducer:

```
const initialState = {
  basePath: 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3',
  apiPath: '/movie/popular',
  lang: 'en-US',
  adult: false,
  genresPath: '/genre/movie/list',
};

const queryReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case API_PATH_UPDATED: {
      return {
        ...state,
        apiPath: action.payload.apiPath,
      };
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default queryReducer;
```

And actually when i click on button that triggers getUpcoming function in Redux devtools i see that action is treggered with right argiments:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TySjh.png)

But it doesn't update state and i see the old apiPath value:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEWDP.png)

Here is the code for my store:

```
import {
  createStore, applyMiddleware, compose, combineReducers,
} from 'redux';
import camelMiddleware from 'redux-camel';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import moviesReducer from './movies/index';
import queryReducer from './query/index';
import genresReducer from './genres/index';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  query: queryReducer,
  movies: moviesReducer,
  genres: genresReducer,
});

const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__({
  trace: true, traceLimit: 25,
}) || compose;

const store = createStore(rootReducer, composeEnhancers(
  applyMiddleware(thunk, camelMiddleware()),
));

export default store;
```

**Thanks everyone for help.**
I found my issue. I forgot to put curly braces around named import in my queryReducer file.

so the line

```
import API_PATH_UPDATED from './queryActions';
```

should be

```
import { API_PATH_UPDATED } from './queryActions';
```

That what happens when coding at 5a.m. :/

Comment: I might be wrong as I am a newbie,  but shouldn't it be just apiPath: action.payload and not action.payload.apiPath?

Comment: you're not setting the response anywhere. It seems like you're missing react-saga's file. where you can send request and receive response

Comment: Can you show where & how you create your store and combine this `queryReducer` into your reducer tree that is passed to the store when it's created? If you are dispatching the action (and see it logged) then try to verify your reducer function and specific case it being called.